# Super Weird Glitch in BottomSheet when open Keyboard in nested Fragment

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I'm having this super weird glitch in my app.

[image: Glitch Gif]

When I open the keyboard and then I inflate another fragment, the `bottomsheet` fragment will scroll till reach the top of the `recyclerview` hiding the top of the `bottomsheet` view.

I have a MainFragment with a two `FragmentContainerView`. The first one is a container where I switch between two fragments (`NestedFragment_0` and `NestedFragment_1`) and the second one I use it to inlfate a fragment that has a BottomSheet. The button switch between two fragments.

It happens just if the `EditText` is inside of one of the nested fragment and if there is a `RecyclerView` inside of the BottomSheet.

I've uploaded the project [here](https://github.com/buntupana/Glitch) if someone wants to download it

**Main Fragment Layout:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/content_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Switch Nested Fragment"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainFragment Code:**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var binding: MainFragmentBinding

    private var activeSubFragment: Fragment = Nested0Fragment()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = MainFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            activeSubFragment = if (activeSubFragment is Nested0Fragment) {
                Nested1Fragment()
            } else {
                Nested0Fragment()
            }
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_container, activeSubFragment).commit()
        }

        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_container, activeSubFragment)
            .commit()

        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.bottom_sheet_container, BottomSheetFragment.newInstance()).commit()

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**BottomSheet Layout:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".ui.main.BottomSheetFragment">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="BottomSheet"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the focus, when the EditText loses the focus the system will give the focus to the RecyclerView and that's why it moves to the top. In Fragment version 1.4.0 the problem it solved for API 28 and above, for API 27 and below it will be just needed to add `focusable=true` and `focusableInTouchMode=true` in the toppest parent view.